# Question about the use of 'unlike'

Tags: grammar

1. The moon is not a magnet the way the earth is.
2. Unlike the earth, the moon is not a magnet.

The first sentence is from an article on science. Can I rewrite the sentence as the second? Please explain it to me.

Comment: In English, we always put a space after a comma, and we do not capitalize the first word after a comma: "Unlike the **earth, the** moon is not a magnet."

Answer (score 4):

> 1. The moon is not a magnet the way the earth is.
> 2. Unlike the earth, the moon is not a magnet.

Regardless of scientific validity, the two sentences  differ in meaning.

1 says that the Moon is a magnet, but, comparing ***the ways*** the Moon and the Earth are magnets, the Moon is not a magnet like the Earth is a magnet; or the Moon is not magnetic to the degree that the Earth is a magnet. 2 says that the Earth is a magnet and the moon is not.
So, 1 and 2 are not equivalent.

I think you are reading 1 as "the moon is not a magnet, but the Earth is", which is in fact equivalent to 2. However, I think that reading of 1 is not entirely correct.

Comment: +1 for ignoring the scientific fallacy, and addressing the question from an English perspective!

Comment: +1 Nice point, I had not spotted **the way**

Answer (score 0):

It works, but it's a bit awkward. Perhaps consider beginning the sentence with "Unlike the Earth..." Also Moon and Earth should be capitalized as they are proper nouns, and it sounds a little funny to be calling them "magnets." Better to call them "magnetic."

> Unlike the Earth, the Moon is not magnetic.

Answer (score -1):

In fact, both moon and earth are giant magnets.

"The magnetic field of the Moon is very weak in comparison to that of the Earth. Other major differences are that the Moon does not currently have a dipolar magnetic field (as would be generated by a geodynamo in its core) and the varying magnetization that is present is almost entirely crustal in origin." 
(from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field_of_the_Moon)

So, in my opinion, sentence 1 is scientifically correct.